# using mapbox to query JSON

Tags: json, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

So I have a set of data stored in my database that is polygon and multipolygon geoJSON data.

I am trying to work out how can I allow a user to search live for a suburb that is in our database and then when they select it, the script maps that area out in the mapbox map.

This only is to show a visual representation to the client what areas that they have selected.

I know how to do it when it is loaded, but we are taking about something that needs to be added on the go.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Add a polygon to a map using a GeoJSON source</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.7.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.7.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<style>
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    // TO MAKE THE MAP APPEAR YOU MUST
    // ADD YOUR ACCESS TOKEN FROM
    // https://account.mapbox.com
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'YOUR_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN';
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map', // container ID
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10', // style URL
center: [-68.137343, 45.137451], // starting position
zoom: 5 // starting zoom
});
 
map.on('load', () => {
// Add a data source containing GeoJSON data.
map.addSource('maine', {
'type': 'geojson',
'data': {
'type': 'Feature',
'geometry': {
'type': 'Polygon',
// These coordinates outline Maine.
'coordinates': [
[
[-67.13734, 45.13745],
[-66.96466, 44.8097],
[-68.03252, 44.3252],
[-69.06, 43.98],
[-70.11617, 43.68405],
[-70.64573, 43.09008],
[-70.75102, 43.08003],
[-70.79761, 43.21973],
[-70.98176, 43.36789],
[-70.94416, 43.46633],
[-71.08482, 45.30524],
[-70.66002, 45.46022],
[-70.30495, 45.91479],
[-70.00014, 46.69317],
[-69.23708, 47.44777],
[-68.90478, 47.18479],
[-68.2343, 47.35462],
[-67.79035, 47.06624],
[-67.79141, 45.70258],
[-67.13734, 45.13745]
]
]
}
}
});
 
// Add a new layer to visualize the polygon.
map.addLayer({
'id': 'maine',
'type': 'fill',
'source': 'maine', // reference the data source
'layout': {},
'paint': {
'fill-color': '#0080ff', // blue color fill
'fill-opacity': 0.5
}
});
// Add a black outline around the polygon.
map.addLayer({
'id': 'outline',
'type': 'line',
'source': 'maine',
'layout': {},
'paint': {
'line-color': '#000',
'line-width': 3
}
});
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is map.querySourceFeatures('maine'), which will return a list of all polygons within your geoJson.

You can then use the .find() function to narrow down that list to the polygon you wish to highlight, get the polygonID from there and perform whatever style changes you wish to see on that polygon.